# Remove a Hash key using except

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a Hash like this:

```
my_hash = {
"user_attributes" => {
     "email" => "email@email.com", 
     "person_attributes" => {
           "first_name" => "a_name", 
           "last_name" => "a_name"
      }
  }
}
```

I want to remove all the `"person_attributes"` content, so I used:

```
my_hash.except("person_attributes")
```

But that does not do anything. How can I remove a sub-hash key?

Comment: Will `personal_attributes` always be in the same place in the hash (user_attributes -> personal_attributes)?

Comment: I think that except is specifically a rails function and not a standard ruby function

Comment: [`except`](http://apidock.com/rails/Hash/except) does not mutate the underlying hash, so you either use [`except!`](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/Hash/except%21) or you mutate the hash yourself

Comment: Ok, I will remove the ruby tag, sorry

Comment: @YoannAugen don't remove the ruby tag, `my_hash.tap { |x| x["user_attributes"].delete("person_attributes") }` is a valid ruby answer here too

Comment: I'm not sure to understand the downvote. It's my question so stupid?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to use this to get the `my_hash['user_attrbiutes'] except person_attributes`:

```
2.1.0 :010 > my_hash['user_attributes'].except('person_attributes')
 => {"email"=>"email@email.com"}
```

To get the output as `{"user_attributes"=>{"email"=>"email@email.com"}}` you can use:

```
 => {"user_attributes"=>{"email"=>"email@email.com", "person_attributes"=>{"first_name"=>"a_name", "last_name"=>"a_name"}}} 
2.1.0 :026 > my_hash['user_attributes'].delete('person_attributes')
 => {"first_name"=>"a_name", "last_name"=>"a_name"} 
2.1.0 :027 > my_hash
 => {"user_attributes"=>{"email"=>"email@email.com"}}
```

Comment: I think that return only the user_attribute sub-key. So you lost the "user_attributes" key reference and if you have other keys at the same level, they will be lost too.

Comment: the result expected is : {"user_attributes"=>{"email"=>"email@email.com"}}

Comment: refer the revisions :)

Comment: Ok it's work too. This and my_hash.tap comment solution are ok for me. thanks!